# Disable synonyms and stemming on a per query basis in Solr

Tags: solr, synonym, stemming

We run a legal search engine. Lawyers, being rather particular generally want synonyms and stemming turned on, but sometimes want to turn them off for certain queries.

For example, we have one user that wants to search for:

```
judgments
```

Not:

```
judgements (with two e's)
```

Or:

```
judgment (singular, not plural)
```

Is there a way to do this? I know it will blow up my index size a bit.

Comment: Google for SOUNDEX functions.

Comment: I'm familiar with soundex, and I just looked up Solr's docs on the topic...how does this help?

Comment: just create a copyField and apply a different filter

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way would be:

1. index this into two fields (use copyField), one with synonyms and one without (index or query time, that decision is orthogonal to this).
2. when running your queries, match against one field or the other depending whether you want synonyms used or not.